# Unusual text inserted before my meta description in SERP

Tags: seo, meta-tags

Can anyone tell me what why the following text appears right before the meta description for all my pages in SERP:

**Items 25 - 100** - Meta Description Text

The site runs on Wordpress with SEO by Yoast.

Comment: Are you using a cms? Are you syncing between say a cms and a inventory management system?

Comment: It a WP site and no syncing

Comment: Have you installed any seo plugins?

Comment: I have used seo by yoast for over a year now.

Comment: Another plugin or theme must be prepending the text to every page

Comment: How would you troubleshoot something like this?

Comment: What's the site address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is thinking that you have pagination and is putting in markup for it.  To power this functionality, Google appears to look for "items ## to ##" anywhere in your text.   You do such text, but not for pagination:

> 3D printing produces items 25 to 100 times faster

I can find it in your source code in an image alt tag.

It looks like a Google bug.   If you want to work around it, you could change that sentence.  Try one of the following:

- 3D printing is 25 to 100 times faster
- 3D printing produces items twenty-five to one-hundred times faster

It looks like you may have already updated an article title to "New 3D Printing Technology Produces Parts from Resin 25 to 100 Times Faster" but did not change the alt text on the image to go along with it.

Comment: Thanks. But why would it do this for every single article on the site and the home page?

Comment: I see that article on your home page and the image alt text is in the source code for your home page.   That article was most likely in your "Most Popular Articles" widget on every page on your site when Google was crawling.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the alt text. Just gotta wait for G to re crawl.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't appear to be on every page. Try identify what pages it occurs and then try find plugins or things in common. It doesn't seem to appear on post pages, the date is being used there. So it could be the theme inserting it in absence of the post date